# Working with Hibernate with un-associated entities

Tags: hibernate

i am working on hibernate and suppose we have two classes A and B (Corresponding to two tables A1 and B1).

A1 table's primary key is being used as a foreign key in B1 table.

```
Class A {

    int aid;
    //other columns

}

class B {

     int bid;
     //other columns
     ....
     //foreign key
     int aid;

}
```

instead of keeping A's reference in class B, I am keeping aid as a foreign key.

But I am not able to use criteria queries in this case for joining these tables.

Is there any solution available?

But my opinion is it is not possible to use criteria because hibernate does not know if the two tables are associated or not, so we should use simple SQL Query to fetch the records.

Comment: Why arent you keeping a reference?

Comment: There is some constraint. I can not keep that in my class.

Comment: Yea if you dont want to use Hibernate specified way, then youll have to write native SQL